# Java: Memory consumption in Activity Monitor on Mac vs JVisualVM

Tags: java, macos, opengl, memory, lwjgl

I am trying to develop a voxel rendering engine in Java with LWJGL 2.

I'm launching my application from Eclipse, and I've set the initial heap size to 1024M and the max heap size to 2048M in the "Run Configurations" menu.

When I look at the memory consumption of my program in Java VisualVM, it shows about 500-1000 MB of used heap to me.

#### Diagram of memory consumption in Java VisualVM

[image: Diagram]

But, the Activity Monitor on Mac shows me that there are 20 GB of RAM used. What could be possible reasons for this enormous discrepancy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The heap size is only used by plain Java objects.

If you are using a native library like LWJQL you can allocate far more native memory.

These native data object often needs to be explicitly freed by calling a method on the object when you don't need it anymore.